# Ruby: what is Hash.new doing here

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm stepping through some Ruby code of a hangman app made with Sinatra. Specifically, I'm looking at the `post "/check" do` path/function below. The first two steps of the function are predictable, namely, it shows the `final_word` variable, and then the `char_clicked` variable, but then the debugger reveals this Hash.new

```
Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
```

before moving on in the function. I don't see why `post "/check"` is creating a new hash at this point. It's not explicit in the code, and it's not obvious to me why this would be happening behind the scenes. I included the correct_guess method below as well, which gets invoked in ``

```
final_word = session[:word]
(rdb:3) n
hangman.rb:79
char_clicked = params[:char_clicked]
(rdb:3) n
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:916
Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
(rdb:3) n
hangman.rb:80
correct_guess = Game.correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)
```

**check path**

```
post "/check" do
  debugger
  final_word = session[:word]
  char_clicked = params[:char_clicked]
  correct_guess = Game.correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)

  if correct_guess
    session[:revealed_word] = Word.reveal(session[:revealed_word], char_clicked, final_word)
    session[:chars_left] = Word.chars_left(session[:revealed_word])
  else
    session[:incorrect_guesses] += 1
  end
  win = Game.win?(session[:chars_left], session[:incorrect_guesses])

  {:word => session[:revealed_word], :correct_guess => correct_guess, :incorrect_guesses => session[:incorrect_guesses], :win => win}.to_json
end
```

Game correct_guess method

```
def correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)
  final_word.include?(char_clicked)
end
```

Comment: What's going on around line 916 of `sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb`?

Comment: I think line 925 is what you're talking about, creating indifferent params hash https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb

Comment: `params` is a method, perhaps it is creating a cached "hash with indifferent access" the first time you call the `params` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinatra is creating the `params` hash for 'indifferent access' (so the hash keys can be accessed by string or symbols interchangeably).

`Hash.new` takes a block to determine what value to return if the key doesn't exist.

Example:

```
>> sh = Hash.new
=> {}
>> sh["key"] = "value"
=> "value"
>> sh[:key]
=> nil

>> ih = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
=> {}
>> ih["key"] = "value"
=> "value"
>> ih[:key]
=> "value"
```

---

When you try to access `params[:char_clicked]` the hash block executes so the debugger dumps the full line containing the block (the hash isn't actually being created at that point):

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
debugger
h["invalid_key"]
```

->

```
sample.rb:5
h["invalid_key"]
(rdb:1) n
sample.rb:3
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
```

When the block is on a separate line the it's easier to see which part of the code is being executed (i.e. just the block):

```
h = Hash.new do 
  |hash, key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key
end
debugger
h["invalid_key"]
```

->

```
sample.rb:7
h["invalid_key"]
(rdb:1) n
sample.rb:4
|hash, key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key
```